# Why is text being cut of here in my Preferences class?

Tags: android, layout, android-preferences

I cant see why the wrap_content here is not working in the custom 'preference'

Look at this picture:

[image]

Text should stay visible right. Is this some setting I have to do in the `PreferenceScreen` xml file?

Here is the xml layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="@string/pref_category_remote_battery_title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:textColor="@color/default_400"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/pref_category_remote_battery_switch_summ"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:showText="true" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />
```

Here is the pref xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.sun.power.extended.preferences.ShowRemoteDataPreference android:key="@string/pref_key_category_remote_battery_switch" />


    <com.sun.power.extended.preferences.ShowStatPreference android:key="@string/pref_key_show_stat" />


</PreferenceScreen>
```